# net use succeeded but account/password check failed for WNetAddConnection2

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I used a small console app in c#, the code was based on gist.github.com/AlanBarber/92db36339a129b94b7dd, to test Windows Networking API WNetAddConnection2 to list files in a specified folder in UNC format. The code worked for most of the cases. It worked in our office and in most of client sites. However, in a particular client site, the app failed with error code 1326 (bad name or password), sometimes with error code 86 (bad password). In this particular client site, "net use" succeeded.

I asked the client side to change the Local Policies "Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level" to "LM and NTLM – use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated" and "LM and NTLM", and still failed.

I also asked the client side to open firewall port 445, 137, 139. The problem still remained.

I wondered what could be the reason for the failure of the code. Any idea?

Comment: Do you ever call WNetAddConnection2 with NULL for credentials?

Comment: In my company, the program run successfully. However, on the client site, the program returned error code 86, which means invalid password. Any comments on these results? Yes, I just modified the credentials to be null.

Comment: Null means last-used, which may not be what you want.

Comment: I got the solution: Before calling WNetAddConnection2, WNetCancelConnection2 should be called. I added that line of code, then the problem was solved! Thank you for leading me to find the solution, Harry.